# Is there a oneliner for ForeinKeyConstraint constructor?

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys, nullreferenceexception, one-liner

I have this piece of code that I need to repeat a lot of times (`dt_Areas` and `dt_Locations` are `DataTable` objects):

```
ForeignKeyConstraint fkC = 
  new ForeignKeyConstraint(dt_Areas.Columns["Id"],
                           dt_Locations.Columns["AreaId"]);
fkC.DeleteRule = Rule.None;
fkC.UpdateRule = Rule.None;
```

In all cases, my `DeleteRule` and `UpdateRule` must be the same.

So I thought, let's look for a constructor, containing rule definitions too, which led me to this piece of code:

```
dt_Locations.Constraints.Add(
  new ForeignKeyConstraint("Location_Areas", 
                           "Areas",
                           "",
                           new string[]{ "AreaId" },
                           new string[] {"Id" }, 
                           AcceptRejectRule.None,
                           Rule.None,
                           Rule.None));
```

This does not work, due to a `NullReferenceException` referring to the `Constraints` property, so let's solve that issue:

```
dt_Locations.Constraints = new ConstraintCollection();
...
```

But this seems not to be allowed, as you can see from this build result:

```
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'DataTable.Constraints' cannot be assigned to --
it is read only
```

First of all, I don't understand where this is coming from: pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> leads me to this piece of code:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[ResCategoryAttribute("DataCategory_Data")]
[ResDescriptionAttribute("DataTableConstraintsDescr")]
public ConstraintCollection Constraints { get; }
```

The property is public and the switches in the preceding lines don't show "read-only" (at least not that I understand).

So my question is: as I have quite a lot of tables to cover, how can I add a constraint at runtime, preferably using a one-liner?

Comment: Create your own specialized class with its own constructor that defaults the rules as you want?

Comment: @SMor: is this a serious answer? I have no idea what you mean, I just want to use the .Net standard classes for DB handling.

Comment: I don't know anything about SQL server, but can't you just do `new ForeignKeyConstraint(dt_Areas.Columns["Id"], dt_Locations.Columns["AreaId"]) { DeleteRule = Rule.None, UpdateRule = Rule.None }`?

Comment: @Sweeper: that's the solution indeed. I have no idea why it works, but this is what I am looking for. Please write it down as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn that code into a single statement, you just need an [object initialiser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers):

```
var fkC = 
  new ForeignKeyConstraint(dt_Areas.Columns["Id"],dt_Locations.Columns["AreaId"])
    { 
        DeleteRule = Rule.None, 
        UpdateRule = Rule.None 
    };
```

... and this piece of code makes it possible to add that constraint to the `DataTable.Constraints` property:

```
dt_Locations.Constraints.Add(
  new ForeignKeyConstraint(dt_Areas.Columns["Id"], 
                           dt_Locations.Columns["AreaId"])
    { DeleteRule = Rule.None, 
      UpdateRule = Rule.None });
```

(This is split over multiple lines for readability reasons, but it can be written as a one-liner very easy.)