# How to treat deletion triggered exceptions, based on a ForeignKeyConstraint?

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys

Yesterday [I asked about how to create a one-liner for `ForeignKeyConstraint` objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68938210), and the proposed solution is working fine.

Now I have following line of source code for creating the `ForeinKeyConstraint` (splitted over multiple lines for readability purposes):

```
dt_Locations.Constraints.Add(
  new ForeignKeyConstraint(dt_Areas.Columns["Id"], 
                           dt_Locations.Columns["AreaId"]) 
  { 
     DeleteRule = Rule.None, 
     UpdateRule = Rule.None
  }
);
```

When I try to delete a row from the `DataTable` `dt_Areas`, while it is being referred to by a `DataTable` `dt_Locations` entry, I get an exception:

```
try
{ 
  dt_Areas.Rows[0].Delete();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show($"You can't do that: [{dt_Locations.Constraints[0].ToString()}] and [{ex.Message}]");
}
```

Now, next part in that story: I would like to change the messagebox into something like:

> "You want to remove 'Area' tupples which are being referred to by 'Locations' tupples. Do you want to remove those 'Locations' tupples and remove the 'Area' tupples afterwards?"

This message being shown with a `MessageBoxButton.YesNo` in the `MessageBox` constructor.

In order to perform do this removal, I need:

```
dt_Areas.TableName;
dt_Locations.TableName;
dt_Areas.Columns["AreasId"].Ordinal;     // in order to know which column I need to take the value from
                                         // that I need for searching in the Locations table.
dt_Locations.Constraints[0].<properties> // properties: "RelatedColumns", "RelatedTable", "Table", ...
```

I am capable of doing that, but it looks like such an enormous burden, that I almost cannot believe such a feature not being provided by the .Net platform.

Am I correct? Is there a simple way to remove the "dependencies" of a constraint?

Thanks in advance

**Edit after first comment from [Caius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard)**

As far as I have understood, there are basically two types of `DeleteRule`s, `None` and `Cascade`, with their own meaning:

- `None` : don't let the tupples be deleted if they are referenced by tupples in other tables.
- `Cascade` : not only delete the tables that are referenced, but the referencing ones too.

What I would like to do, is to show a "warning" message, something like this here:

[image: Screenshot]

Answering "Yes" would cause **all** the tupples to be deleted.
Answering "No" would cause **none** of the tupples to be deleted.

This comes down to this (erroneous) code:

```
try
{ 
  dt_Areas.Rows[0].Delete();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  if (MessageBox.Show("In order to .... Is that what you want?",
                      "Warning",
                      MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
  {
    (ForeignKeyConstraint)(dt_Locations.Constraints[0]).DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade;
    dt_Areas.Rows[0].Delete();
    (ForeignKeyConstraint)(dt_Locations.Constraints[0]).DeleteRule = Rule.None;
  }
}
```

However, as mentioned, this code is erroneous, because it seems not to be possible to alter the `DeleteRule` at runtime, hereby the compilation result:

```
error CS1061: 'Constraint' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteRule' 
and no accessible extension method 'DeleteRule' accepting
a first argument of type 'Constraint' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not just set DeleteRule to Cascade?

Comment: [It's a writable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.foreignkeyconstraint.deleterule?view=net-5.0) ...

Comment: If it's a writable property, why am I having that compiler error?

Comment: That error is not what you would see if the property was read only ("...cannot be assigned to"). It is what you see when you attempt to access a member of a type and that member doesn't exist (in this case your specific derived class is within a more generic parent type) Cast the constraint to ForeignKeyConstraint before you set the property; `((ForeignKeyConstraint)x).DeleteRule ...`

Comment: I thought that was what I did but I had forgotten about a pair of brackets :-) Such mistakes are a clear indication that I'm tired and that I should leave and start the weekend, which is exactly what I will do :-) Can you write your suggestion as an answer? I'll accept it (on Monday, of course, because now I start the weekend :-) )

Comment: (Or if you have other constraints inspect  the type first : `if(someconstraint is ForeignKeyConstraint fk) fk.DeleteRule = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to toggle the behavior of the constraint at runtime by e.g.

```
    ((ForeignKeyConstraint)dt_Locations.Constraints[0]).DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade
```

If your FK will not always be the first constraint, you might have to look for it with eg

```
foreach(Constraint c in dt_Locations.Constraints)
  if(c is ForeignKeyConstraint fk ...)
    fk.DeleteRule = ....
```

You can replace the three dots with additional logic such as inspecting the name, if you need..